# Find Groovy Closure by name

Tags: groovy

I try to call a dynamic closure in Groovy, and I'm stuck right now. I have the name, but I don't know how to reference it with the `call()` method

Here is a small example of what I want to achieve:

```
def fooClos = { println foo }
def barClos = { println bar}
def c = new Random().nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar"
"${c}Clos".call()
```

So the last line should either print `foo` or `bar`

I also tried

```
this."${c}Clos".call()
```

and

```
this.&"${c}Clos".call()
```

without any success.
So can someone help me how the correct reference has to look? I can probably work around my problem, but I still want to know how it is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works if you don't use `def` for your closures ([so they go into the binding of the script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22))

```
fooClos = { println 'foo' }
barClos = { println 'bar' }
def c = new Random().nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar"
"${c}Clos"()
```

It also works if you mark them with the `@Field` annotation so they get added as fields of the generated Script class:

```
import groovy.transform.*

@Field def fooClos = { println 'foo' }
@Field def barClos = { println 'bar' }
def c = new Random().nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar"
"${c}Clos"()
```

*A bit more explanation*

The original way you had it effectively compiles to:

```
public java.lang.Object run() {
    java.lang.Object fooClos = { 
        return this.println('foo')
    }
    java.lang.Object barClos = { 
        return this.println('bar')
    }
    c = new java.util.Random().nextInt() % 2 == 0 ? 'foo' : 'bar'
    return this."$cClos"()
}
```

So `fooClos` and `barClos` are local variables in the `run` method.  It then tries to call `this.fooClos` or `this.barClos`, which obviously fails

Comment: wow, great answer! I ended up putting the closures in a map where I can get them by any name I want. But now I understand why it didn't work before.